# How to clear the deployment history of a repository?

Tags: github, deployment, repository, github-pages

[image]

=-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------=
When we deploy a project in GitHub, how can only the active deployment be displayed in the environment section after each commit and update?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your question, more Deployment, it's part of Github Environments, currently you seem to have Github-pages as an active environment in your repository, each time you deploy to github-pages it will show there, always the last deployment as active and the previous ones are inactive, I see no option to clear this deployment history, maybe you can delete the github-pages environment and the deployment history disappears, but I'm not sure.

Maybe using github API you can do some things with Deployments, see this link for more info:

- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/deployments?apiVersion=2022-11-28

You can see your active environments in this link:

```
https://github.com/<owner>/<repo>/settings/environments
```

Hope this helps.